# Iterating unknown JSON in Pug/Jade

Tags: node.js, express, iteration, pug, sequelize.js

I'm working on building my first api with node/express and trying to create a simple Jade view that will render JSON across a bunch of different models, so I don't want to have to create a different view for every model I have. I just want to iterate over any response and spit out the results in a table. Is there a general version that will do this?

This is what I have in my express file:

```
/*  Post a STATE and send to update.jade view*/

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    State.build(req.body).save()
        .then(function(State){
            res.render("update", {
                title: "States Post",
                data: State
            });

        })
});

/*  GET all STATES and send to a update.jade view */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    State.findAll().then(function(States){
        res.render("update", {
            title: "States Get All",
            data: States
        });
    })
});
```

And here's what I currently have in the jade view:

```
extends layout
block content
    h1= title
    table
        each value, index in data
            tr
                td= index
                td= value
```

As a result for the get call I have:

```
States Get All

0   [object SequelizeInstance:State]
```

And for the post it spits out:

```
States Post

dataValues  [object Object]
_previousDataValues [object Object]
_changed    [object Object]
$modelOptions   [object Object]
$options    [object Object]
hasPrimaryKeys  true
__eagerlyLoadedAssociations 
isNewRecord false
_customGetters  [object Object]
_customSetters  [object Object]
validators  [object Object]

(etc. it goes on...)
```

Any help is uber appreciated. I'm storing in a Postgres database and using Sequelize, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cane use `toJSON()` method on every instance of sequelize model, which will return a javascript object with `key : value` pairs, where every `key` is an attribute of previously defined sequelize model

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    State.build(req.body).save()
        .then(function(State){
            res.render("update", {
                title: "States Post",
                data: State.toJSON() // will return simple object
            });

        })
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    State.findAll().then(function(States){
        res.render("update", {
            title: "States Get All",
            data: return States.map((state) => { return state.toJSON(); }); // this will create an array of simple objects
        });
    })
});
```

---

**EDIT**

You can also use `{ raw: true }` in the `findAll()` method. It will result in not creating any instances of model. It will simply return specified columns from the database without any formatting.

> If true, sequelize will not try to format the results of the query, or build an instance of a model from the result

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed - simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is display the raw json code, you could do something like this:

`block content
    code=JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)`

If the iteration itself is important, like if you need to do something to each element in your json data, you could implement data traversal with a recursive mixin (the one I've implemented here is a list, but you could conceivably do something similar with a table, somehow):

```
mixin traverse(data)
  if Array.isArray(data)
    ul
      each value in data
        li
          +traverse(value)
  else if typeof data === 'object'
    dl
      each value, index in data
        dt=index
        dd
          +traverse(value)
  else
    span=data
```